# Помогите с загрузкой картинок в вк

Tags: java, android, вконтакте

Делаю парсер под ВК. На стене все отображается, кроме картинок! Не понимаю почему!

```
if(!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) {
            loginVK.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
            VKRequest reqWall=VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from("owner_id", owner_id, VKSdk.getAccessToken().userId, VKApiConst.EXTENDED, 1, VKApiConst.COUNT,200 ,VKApiConst.FIELDS, "text"));
            reqWall.setPreferredLang("ru");
            reqWall.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    super.onComplete(response);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.json;
                    String owner = null;
                    try {
                        owner = (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("items")).get(0)).getString("owner_id"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    VKPostArray posts = new VKPostArray();
                    try {
                        posts.parse(response.json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("groups"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    VKApiPost p = posts.get(0);
                    VKAttachments at = p.attachments;
                    VKAttachments.VKApiAttachment test = at.get(0);
                    imageLoader.getInstance();
                    try {
                        Log.v("test", (((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("response")).get("profiles")).get(0)).getString("id")));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.userWall);
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    RecyclerAdapterWall adapterWall = new RecyclerAdapterWall(getApplicationContext(), posts);
                    rv.setAdapter(adapterWall);
```

---

```
public class RecyclerAdapterWall extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterWall.ViewHolder>{
    Context ctx;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String owner_id;
    VKPostArray obj;

    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts)
    {
        //super(ctx,R.layout.recycler_item_wall);
        this.obj= posts;
        this.ctx= ctx;
        imageLoader.getInstance();

    }
    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts, String owner_id)
    {
        //super(ctx,R.layout.recycler_item_wall);
        this.obj= posts;
        this.ctx= ctx;
        this.owner_id= owner_id;
        imageLoader.getInstance();

    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final VKApiPost p= obj.get(position);
        holder.imageWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
        java.util.Date time= new java.util.Date((long)p.date*1000);
        holder.textDatePost.setText(String.valueOf(time));
        //new GetUsersTask(holder.textNamePost,holder.imageWall,ctx).execute(String.valueOf(p.from_id));
        new GetUsersTask(holder.textNamePost, holder.imageWall, ctx, imageLoader).execute(String.valueOf(p.from_id));


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }
    public static class ViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        CardView cv;
        TextView textNamePost;
        TextView textDatePost;
        TextView textPost;
        ImageView imageWall;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);
            textDatePost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            //textNamePost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNamePost);
            textPost=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
            imageWall=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageWall);

        }
    }
}
```

=================================================

```
public class GetUsersTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, VKApiUser> {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Context context;
    VKApiUser vkApiUser;

    public GetUsersTask(TextView textView,ImageView imageView,Context context,ImageLoader imageLoader)
    {
        this.textView=textView;
        this.imageView=imageView;
        this.context=context;
        this.imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance();

    }

    protected VKApiUser doInBackground(String... id) {
        String ID = id[0];

        final VKApiUser[] user1 = new VKApiUser[1];
        VKRequest request= VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, ID,VKApiConst.FIELDS,"photo_100"));
        request.setPreferredLang("ru");
        request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                VKList<VKApiUser> us = ((VKList<VKApiUser>) response.parsedModel);
                user1[0] = us.get(0);
            }
        });
        return user1[0];
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(VKApiUser result) {
        if(result!=null) {
            textView.setText(result.first_name + " " + result.last_name);
            /*imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
            DisplayImageOptions options=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                    .build();
*/
            imageLoader.displayImage(result.photo_100, imageView);
            Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(result.photo_100)
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ну и ? где сам код то ? всё в GetUsersTask делается и вы нам его не показываете?

Answer (score -2):

попробуй использовать библиотеку Retrofit 2 для загрузки данных и парса json

вот пример использования http://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

а  для загрузки картинок можешь попробовать Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: да да да не добавляют знаний в ру нет, умный человек должен сам ориентироваться как использовать, но ему лишь надо показать что использовать.